# media_sideload_image results in http error (500)

Tags: uploads, media

I want to import a external image with media_sideload_image, but I get the HTTP-Code 500.

What is wrong with my code?

```
function test() {
    media_sideload_image("https://s.w.org/style/images/wp-header-logo.png?1", 1261, null, "id");
}
add_action("init", "test");
```

I want to import a external Image and generate the image sizes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `media_sideload_image()` function is only available in the admin by default, and `init` runs on all page loads.

See the [Codex article](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_sideload_image):

> If you want to use this function outside of the context of /wp-admin/
>   (typically if you are writing a more advanced custom importer script)
>   you need to include media.php and depending includes:
>
> ```
> require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
> require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
> require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
> ```